# Existence of a cts. function $f \geq 0$ satisfying $\int f(x)^n \, dx =1$ for all $n \geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$ that satisfies

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^n d L^1 = 1 $$

for every natural $n$? ($L^1$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: uhmmmm... **continues**. It's not very continues in 0 and 1, is it?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts/attempts to share?

Comment: I tried with $e^{-x^2}$, and I can construct a series of functions, $f_n$, that satisfy $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n^n dx=1$:$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \left(\sqrt[2n]{\frac{n}{\pi }}e^{-x{}^{\wedge}2}\right)^n \, dx,$$, but I cannot think of one specific function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Suppose such $f$ does exist to reach a contradiction.  Then $\sup\limits_{x\in \mathbb R}f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\int_{\mathbb R} f^n dL\right)^{1/n}=1$, so $f(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$.  Hence $f-f^2$ is a nonnegative function, and by continuity $f-f^2$ is not always zero.  This implies (again using continuity) that $\int_{\mathbb R} f-f^2 dL>0$.

Comment: @user19502: You're going through initiation where you can't do much on the website until you earn more points.  More info is in the FAQ.

Comment: Yeah, but I thought that *thanking* someone is not a privilege.

Comment: " is not always zero. " This, thanks to continuity, happens on a set of Lebesgue measure > 0 , right?

Comment: And with a bit more work, you can prove that any measurable function with $\int f^n\ dx = 1$ for all positive integers $n$ is (almost everywhere) the indicator function of a set of measure $1$.

Comment: @user19502: Yes, I added in parentheses subsequently that the last part also uses continuity.  If a continuous function is positive at a point, then it is bounded below by a positive number in a neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Yes, I know that, English is not my native language, just wanted to clarify. Thanks again. Have a mental upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there were a function $f$ with the desired properties. Let us first prove that $$f \leq 1.$$

Indeed, if $\{f>1\}$ had strictly positive Lebesgue measure, then we could find $\epsilon>0$ such that $L^1(\{f \geq 1+\epsilon\})>0$, and so

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x)^n \, dx \geq \int_{\{f \geq 1+\epsilon\}} f(x)^n \, dx \geq (1+\epsilon)^n L^1(\{f \geq 1+ \epsilon\}).$$ Since $\epsilon>0$, the right-hand side converges to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, and this contradicts our assumption that $\int f(x)^n \, dx \leq 1$ for all $n \geq 1$. Hence, $f \leq 1$ Lebesgue almost everywhere. By continuity of $f$, this gives $f \leq 1$ (everywhere).

Since $f \leq 1$, the function $f-f^2$ is non-negative. On the other hand, we have

$$\int (f(x)-f(x)^2) \, dx = \int f(x) \, dx - \int f(x)^2 \, dx = 1-1=0.$$

This implies $f-f^2=0$ almost everywhere. Again we can use continuity to get $f-f^2=0$ (everywhere). Hence,

$$f(x) (1-f(x))=0, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Since $0 \leq f \leq 1$, we conclude that $f(x) \in \{0,1\}$ for all $x$ which is impossible because $f$ is continuous.

**Remark:**  The continuity of $f$ is only needed to discuss away exceptional sets and at the very end of the proof. Thus, the proof actually gives the following more general result.

> Let $f \geq 0$ be a measurable function (not necessarily continuous) such that $$\int f(x)^n \, dx = 1, \qquad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$ Then there exists a set $A$ of Lebesgue measure $1$ such that $f(x)=1_A(x)$.

*Proof:* Following the above proof, we get $$f(x) (1-f(x)) =0 \quad \text{and} \quad 0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$$ Lebesgue almost everywhere. Thus $f(x) \in \{0,1\}$ almost everywhere. If we set $A=\{f=1\}$, the assertion follows.